# regex to check whether json objects contains two specific KV pairs

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to check whether a JSON object contains two particular KV pairs, irrespective of the order.

For example, in the JSON object below:

```
{"color":"red","animal":"dog","drink":"water","food":"pizza","fish":"tuna","foo":"bar"}
```

I want to check whether it contains **both** `"animal":"dog"` **AND** `"fish":"tuna"`.

The following regex works only if the order of the KV pairs are as provided above.

```
^.*(("animal":"dog").*("fish":"tuna")).*$
```

It does not work for when the order is changed as follows:

`{"color":"red","drink":"water","food":"pizza","fish":"tuna","foo":"bar","animal":"dog"}`

How can I check for any order of KV pairs?

Comment: I think the answer re:JSON is parse the JSON as a JSON file, and then go from there

Comment: Don't think you need regex for this as the text you want to find is fixed. Just check if your json string contains `"animal":"dog"` and `"fish":"tuna"` and return `true` if it contains both strings.

Comment: What tool/platform/language are you using? Surely there will be a better way than using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure regex is the best tool here. As you're working with json, it'd probably be best to work with a json-specific tool.

For example, if you have access to a tool such a [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/), you could use eg.

```bash
jq '.animal == "dog" and .fish == "tuna"'
```

The order in which the key-value pairs appear in the json is not important here.

See with your input data, that the above query will return `true`:

```bash
echo '{"color":"red","animal":"dog","drink":"water","food":"pizza","fish":"tuna","foo":"bar"}' | jq '.animal == "dog" and .fish == "tuna"'
# true
```

If either of the key value pairs are missing, or incorrect, you'll receive a false:

```bash
echo '{"color":"red","animal":"cat","drink":"water","food":"pizza","fish":"tuna","foo":"bar"}' | jq '.animal == "dog" and .fish == "tuna"'
# false
```

```bash
echo '{"color":"red","animal":"dog","drink":"water","food":"pizza","pet":"tuna","foo":"bar"}' | jq '.animal == "dog" and .fish == "tuna"'
# false
```

---

I note that you've asked other questions about Python, so if you want a Python solution, it can be as simple as converting your json to a dict and then checking for existence of the key-value pairs:

```py
import json


data = json.loads('{"color":"red","animal":"dog","drink":"water","food":"pizza","fish":"tuna","foo":"bar"}')

data["animal"] == "dog" and data["fish"] == "tuna"
```

---

If you're completely set on using regex (I really don't think it is a good choice here, but ultimately it's your call), you *could* simply use an `|` to check for both possible orders, as, eg.

```
^.*(("animal":"dog").*("fish":"tuna")|("fish":"tuna").*("animal":"dog")).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/qxvJu2/1

Answer (score 0):

Please use this. It may help you

```
const jsonString1 = '{"color":"red","animal":"dog","drink":"water","food":"pizza","fish":"tuna","foo":"bar"}';
const jsonString2 = '{"color":"red","drink":"water","food":"pizza","fish":"tuna","foo":"bar","animal":"dog"}';

const regex = /^(?=.*\b"animal":"dog"\b)(?=.*\b"fish":"tuna"\b).*/;

console.log(regex.test(jsonString1)); // Output: true
console.log(regex.test(jsonString2)); // Output: true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).